#  Non-activeX DLL in a VB6 application fails to load in Outlook 2010

Tags: dll, com, vb6, outlook

I have a VB6 app that utilizes a non-activeX DLL (non-registering).

It's declared via the classic `Public Declare Function "Function Name" Lib "Library.DLL"` syntax.

On my dev machine (XP) it works fine but when I deploy to Vista or Win7 I'm constantly greeted with a Run Time Error 48 - File Not Found for the DLL in question.

I have tried copying that DLL to every directory I can think of including every environment path on the test machine and the app path too.

These are all 32-bit test environments so it's not a SysWow64 issue.

Possibly throwing a wrench into the mix is the fact that the application in question is an Outlook COM Addin.

I managed to install VB6 on Win7 and was able to run a tiny sample app that utilizes this DLL (outside of the Outlook process) so I know it works PROVIDED the DLL is located in App path.  If I call `App.Path` from my DLL when I run it on the test environment it shows, to no surprise, my installation directory however the DLL is there.

I tried turning off UAC.  I tried making the `App.Path` directory permissions open to everyone, still no dice.

Comment: have you tried logging the processes' file accesses with procmon from the SysInternals suite? That's the approach I would take, that usually gives a good hint whether it's a permission problem or something else...

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about ProcMon.  It was able to - seemingly - verify that the DLL is being found.  It seems there's another point of failure however.  It's my understanding that Error 48 is sort of a catch-all for various issues that may arise.  I'm just not sure how to diagnose them seeing how it's a third party DLL.

Comment: UPDATE:  I set up a VM with VB6 and set up a Win 7 development environment.  I can't build the project because of some licensing issues with some other legacy third party components but I was able to replicate the issue (File Not Found) while running in debug.

If I place the DLL in VB6 runtime directory while debugging it works however (C:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb98\).  Not sure what that tells us, but it's good to see the app running on a Win 7 machine.

Comment: OK.  It seems as if when it's running in the VB6.exe process (regardless of OS), it works fine.  It'll run through the entire search order until it finds the DLL and load it without issue.  If I build it and run under the Outlook process, something is causing it to fail internally.

Comment: The ProcMan logs of my DLL activity regardless of environment (compiled running under Outlook.EXE process where it fails or debug running under VB6 when it works) look identical.  Nothing that would indicate a failure.  I'm stumped.. unless there's a dependency that's required when running inproc that doesn't exist I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: not sure whether it's relevant in VB, but in native code there's usually a debug and release runtime, and if you use one while your library is expecting the other, things break. and you could check your windows event log, if there are any helpful entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the DLL's own dependancies. You will get the same error if it couldn't load the DLL in question or some DLL 20 levels deep in the dependancy chain.

Comment: I'm looking into dependencies now.  My only issue with this is that if I run a tiny sample app - installed onto the same test environment that is failing when run as an add-in - the DLL loads.  So the dependencies seems to be in place, suggesting the issue lies with the manner in which the DLL is being utilized (in-proc addin).

Comment: 00:00:37.718: LoadLibraryA("SkinFeatureVB6.dll") returned NULL. Error: Invalid access to memory location (998).

Comment: Ok, the problem was DEP in Outlook 2010, turning it off did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

According to the details you give, it looks like placing the DLL in the path of standard [Add-in locations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286897) would help.

Comment: The add-in folder was one of MANY directories I placed the DLL in question.

Comment: I am not sure it has been suggested, but you might try to profile the app consuming the DLL using dependencywalker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) in profiling mode. In this mode, you should see the location your DLL is loaded from...

Comment: I tried that... problem is I can't profile (or don't know how to). It's a non-registering DLL that is late binded (and fails when it does) so the Profile option is eternally greyed out.  If i'm doing something wrong here, please advise.  Thanks.  

And as noted, the same DLL, stuffed in the same location, loads fine if ran from a test app and not through Outlook as an add-in.

Comment: FWIW, when loading the DLL on my test environment the notification I receive are as follows (see link).

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5064321/depends.png

Comment: OK.  So I profiled for Outlook.EXE and sure enough we have an error:
00:00:37.718: LoadLibraryA("SkinFeatureVB6.dll") returned NULL. Error: Invalid access to memory location (998).

SkinFeatureVB6.DLL is the DLL in question here.

Comment: Here's the full transaction.  There was an access violation a few lines up which could be the cause.

Loaded "c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\SKINFEATUREVB6.DLL" at address 0x10000000 by thread 1 "Main".  Successfully hooked module.
00:00:15.109: DllMain(0x10000000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\SKINFEATUREVB6.DLL" called by thread 1 "Main".
00:00:15.125: First chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred in "c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\SKINFEATUREVB6.DLL" at address 0x10001000 by thread 1 "Main".

Comment: 00:00:15.125: Unloaded "c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\SKINFEATUREVB6.DLL" at address 0x10000000 by thread 1 "Main".
00:00:15.125: LoadLibraryA("SkinFeatureVB6.dll") returned NULL by thread 1 "Main". Error: Invalid access to memory location (998).

Comment: Well, in case anyone's still following along... the problem has been distilled to an Outlook 2010 problem.

I installed Office 2003 (what I build against on XP) and 2007 on Vista and Win7, and sure enough, they work fine.  So there's something specific about the Office 2010 architecture that is tripping me up.

Comment: OK.. Another update.  The problem was DEP in Outlook 2010, turning it off does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first place a DLL search looks is the directory that the EXE loaded from, so your DLL's App.Path won't be used.

Are you sure that you tried installing this DLL into System32?  Into Windows?

Aside from that you should be ble to create a PATH (messy) or an isolation manifest for the calling code (VB6 if I'm following you) that specifies DLL Redirection to a relative path (i.e. a subfolder under the folder with your VB6 code in it).

See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm still trying to get to the bottom of this but it seems (through ProcMon) as if it correctly finds the DLL; iterating down the DLL search order chain until it does.